# How to adjust future.global.maxSize?

Tags: r, future

Here's a useless example that shows my point

```r
library(future)
a = 1:200000000
object.size(a)
test %<-% head(a)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in getGlobalsAndPackages(expr, envir = envir, persistent =
> persistent,  : The total size of all global objects that need to be
> exported for the future expression (‘head(a)’) is 762.95 MiB. This
> exceeds the maximum allowed size of 500.00 MiB (option
> 'future.global.maxSize'). There are two globals:  ‘a’ (762.94 MiB of
> class ‘numeric’) and ‘head’ (10.05 KiB of class ‘function’).

Can anyone help me understand how to adjust that future.global.maxSize option? I tried `options(future.global.maxSize = 1500000)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Got it figured out and learned how you can edit options for any package.

This is the line that I used (edit: the change was from 'global' to 'globals':

```
options(future.globals.maxSize= 891289600)
```

If you want to customize your limit, I saw in the package source that the limit was calculated and this is how you would calculate the size for an 850mb limit:

```
850*1024^2 = 891289600
```

Thanks!

Comment: Author of future here: This is correct; use option `future.globals.maxSize` (plural) - there was a typo in the error message.  This has been fixed for next release (future > 1.2.0), cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/116

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for adding the note and thank you for the great package.

Comment: @HenrikB nice work on this package! I just encountered this error message, and it made me realize that I would be needlessly consuming resources. Very helpful!

Comment: So if there are 10 cores and 64 GB RAM. Should `future.globals.maxSize` be 64 or 6.4 GB? In short, I don't want any limits. It should be able to use all the RAM that is available.

Comment: Setting maxsize only impacts the maximum amount of data that is passed to the new future process, not how much RAM it can use.